# How to store special characters in sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite, foreign-keys, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I have text and blog types for two columns..
When ever I use special chars like `; / =` etc. Sqlite is raising OperationalError.
I am using python sqlite3 api..

Why this is happening and how to fix it?

**edit1**

this is the table:

```
create table mycontent(
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    subject text not null,
    body text not null
);
```

The below is typically I get error when for example there is a character `;` in `subject` field

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ";": syntax error
```

However when I try to store simple values like `"1"` in all fields.. its working

**edit2**

```
cursor.execute("""
            INSERT INTO mycontent
                (subject, body) 
            VALUES (%s, %s);
        """ % (kwargs["subject"], kwargs["body"])
        )
```

Comment: How are you using those "special" characters... how are you using sqlite3 etc... You need to provide a lot more information before anyone stands a chance of being able to answer... Some example data that reproduces the problem would also be good

Comment: Right.... and where's the query that's causing that error? I have a feeling you're not using parameters here and instead you're using string interpolation to try and put the data in... But, can't know for sure until you show us...

Comment: @JonClements The above is my query..

Answer (score 1):

```
cursor.execute("""
            INSERT INTO mycontent
                (subject, body) 
            VALUES (?, ?);
        """, (kwargs["subject"], kwargs["body"]) 
        )
```

its `?`